# How can i check if input array filed type file empty doesn't upload

Tags: php, javascript, html

How can i check array input type file is empty before upload data in database. if have one empty show anything that user understand and don't updata data.

This is example code html

```
 <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
 <table class="form-table">
     <tr>
     <th><label for="Upload">Upload</label></th>
     <td>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
        <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
        <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
        <br/>
    </form>
     </td>
 </table>
```

I used to use $x=$_GET['profile_photo']; and echo $x; before upload to database and it return empty or null.

Comment: Check `$_FILES` array for count.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$x=$_POST['profile_photo'];` ?

Comment: You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` tag too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x=$_FILES['profile_photo']['name'];
```

USE THIS CODE

Comment: USING $_FILES[] NOT $_GET[]

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!empty($_FILES) && is_array($_FILES)) {

  // you have files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run a for loop on the post data and verify

```
$error = "";
$emptyFiles="";
$i=0;
foreach ($_FILES['profile_photo'] as $name) {
   if (isset($name['name']) && $name['name']!="") {
       $error.="";
   } else {
       $error.= "yes";
       $emptyFiles.=$_FILES['profile_photo'][$i];
   }
    $i++;
}
```

Then use

$error and $emptyFiles string to get which are empty fields and which are not.

Comment: It would be better to check the `$name['error']` value each time rather than if the name is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate inputs by javascript before submission

html:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateInputs();">
    <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
    <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
    <input name="profile_photo[]" type="file"  value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
validateInputs = function() {    
    inputs = document.getElementsByName('profile_photo[]');
    for (var ind in inputs){
        if (inputs[ind].value=="") {
            alert("validation failed");
            return false;
        }
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**in javascript/jquery**

```
var file = $(".profile_photo").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();


for(var i=0; i<file.length; i++){
   if( file[i] == ""){
     alert("Please select file");
     return false;
   }
}
```

**in PHP**

```
if( $_FILES['profile_photo']['error'] != 0 ){
   // code to handle if there is no file selected
}
```